# Second order differential is nan when using 'torch.autograd.grad'

Tags: pytorch, interpolation, torch, derivative, autograd

I want to construct an interpolated function, and do a differential and a second differential on this function, but the second differential always shows as nan.

Here is a given set of data mu_data, I have done interpolation. In order to use it under the framework of PyTorch, I extract the coefficients of the interpolation function and reconstruct a function.

```
# data obtained 
len_data = 10
x_data = np.linspace(0.1, 0.95, len_data, dtype=np.float32)
mu_data = 1/2 * log(1 - x_data) 
mu_interp = interp1d(x_data, mu_data.real, kind='cubic', fill_value='extrapolate')  # function of interpolation

mu_coefficients = CubicSpline(x_data,mu_data).c            # Create a cubic spline interpolation. Access the coefficients
mu_coefficients_Tensor = torch.tensor(mu_coefficients).t() # Transpose the coefficients tensor
```

```
# input
len_input = 20
x_input = torch.tensor(np.linspace(0.14, 0.87, len_input, dtype=np.float32), requires_grad=True).reshape(len_input, 1)  
x_ext = x_input.unsqueeze(-1)             # Extend x's shape to allow broadcasting
x_data_Tensor = torch.tensor(x_data)      # Original x values
mask = torch.where((x_ext >= x_data_Tensor[:-1]) & (x_ext <=x_data_Tensor[1:]), torch.tensor(1), torch.tensor(0))
```

```
def cubic_spline_interpolation(x, coefficients_Tensor):

    x_rel =  (x.unsqueeze(-1)  - x_data_Tensor[:-1]) * mask
    exponents = torch.tensor([3, 2, 1, 0])          
    polynomial_terms = x_rel[..., None] ** exponents[None, None, :]
    interpolated_terms = coefficients_Tensor * polynomial_terms * mask[..., None]
    y = torch.sum(interpolated_terms, dim=(-1, -2))
    return y

def mu_torch(x):
    mu_interp_values = cubic_spline_interpolation(x, mu_coefficients_Tensor)
    result = mu_interp_values + 0j
    return result
```

Here is a comparison of the interpolation made by the two methods：

```
mu_interp_torch = mu_torch(x_input)
mu_interp_scipy = mu_interp(x_input.detach().numpy())
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5F5PP.png)

Since the function values I need are complex numbers, I wrote a differential function for complex numbers:

```
def Derivative(outputs, inputs):

    re_outputs = torch.real(outputs)
    # print("re_outputs = ", re_outputs)

    im_outputs = torch.imag(outputs)
    # print("im_outputs = ", im_outputs)

    d_re = torch.autograd.grad(re_outputs, inputs, grad_outputs=torch.ones_like(re_outputs), retain_graph=True, create_graph=True)[0]
    print("d_re = ", d_re)

    d_im = torch.autograd.grad(im_outputs, inputs, grad_outputs=torch.ones_like(im_outputs), retain_graph=True, create_graph=True)[0]
    print("d_im = ", d_im)

    result = d_re + (0 + 1j) * d_im
    return result
  

mu_prime = Derivative(mu_torch(x_input), x_input)  # Compute the first derivative of the interpolated values with respect to x and store the result in mu_prime
mu_double_prime = Derivative(mu_prime, x_input)
```

```
# The value of the first differential:
d_re =  tensor([[-0.5813],
[-0.6082],
[-0.6382],
[-0.6715],
[-0.7080],
[-0.7487],
[-0.7941],
[-0.8452],
[-0.9051],
[-0.9740],
[-1.0521],
[-1.1395],
[-1.2452],
[-1.3917],
[-1.5782],
[-1.7760],
[-1.9748],
[-2.3160],
[-3.0592],
[-4.2099]], grad_fn=<SqueezeBackward1>)
d_im =  tensor([[0.],
[0.],
[0.],
[0.],
[0.],
[0.],
[0.],
[0.],
[0.],
[0.],
[0.],
[0.],
[0.],
[0.],
[0.],
[0.],
[0.],
[0.],
[0.],
[0.]], grad_fn=<SqueezeBackward1>)
```

```
# The value of the second differential:
d_re =  tensor([[nan],
        [nan],
        [nan],
        [nan],
        [nan],
        [nan],
        [nan],
        [nan],
        [nan],
        [nan],
        [nan],
        [nan],
        [nan],
        [nan],
        [nan],
        [nan],
        [nan],
        [nan],
        [nan],
        [nan]], grad_fn=<SqueezeBackward1>)
d_im =  tensor([[nan],
        [nan],
        [nan],
        [nan],
        [nan],
        [nan],
        [nan],
        [nan],
        [nan],
        [nan],
        [nan],
        [nan],
        [nan],
        [nan],
        [nan],
        [nan],
        [nan],
        [nan],
        [nan],
        [nan]], grad_fn=<SqueezeBackward1>)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rpuUD.png)

I checked the documentation to make sure my code was set up to be able to do higher order differentiation. And this function can correctly calculate the second-order differential before interpolation. I guess there is a problem with the newly constructed interpolation function, which causes the second-order differential to not be calculated.

What I expect is that the second order differential of the function `mu_torch(x)` can be calculated correctly using `torch.autograd.grad.`